# How to custom order JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string that looks something like this:

```
{
   "SignedSubscriptionRule":{
      "User rights":"something1",
      "Function":"something2",
      "Method name":"something3"
   },
   "CancelZeroSubscriptionRule":{
      "User rights":"something4",
      "Function":"something5",
      "Method name":"something6"
   },
   "NewLoanAllocationRule":{
      "User rights":"something7",
      "Function":"something8",
      "Method name":"something9"
   }
}
```

Let's say I receive this JSON on daily basis and each time I have to reorder it to meet my needs. 
How could I defined a custom order of this JSON. Let's say I want it to have the following order:
SignedSubscriptionRule, NewLoanAllocationRule, CancelZeroSubscriptionRule

I'm coding in Java.
I would like to avoid writing my own iterating solution.

Comment: Why do you need to reorder JSON? It has no concept of order (except in the arrays of course), as it's key-value based. What library are you processing that with?

Answer (score 0):

Just notice that ordering in JSON has no meaning except rare cases.

for example:

```
{ "foo": "test", "bar": "test2" }
```

and

```
{ "bar": "test2", "foo": "test" }
```

are the same.

by the way if you need to sort it, you need to write a comparator to set your rules for sorting, like this:

```
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
     private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
     @Override
     public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
        String str1 = new String();
        String str2 = new String();
        try {
           str1 = (String)a.get(KEY_NAME);
           str2 = (String)b.get(KEY_NAME);
        } catch(JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
     }
  });
```

more info on:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-we-sort-a-jsonarray-in-java